# applicationWillHide not called

Tags: swift, macos

I've implemented four functions at my appDelegate:

```
func applicationWillHide(_ notification: Notification) 
func applicationWillUnhide(_ notification: Notification)
func applicationWillResignActive(_ notification: Notification) 
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification)
```

I tried to hide the app/minimize it, but none of them is getting called.

I also tried to add a observer for the notification - don't think it's needed but tried it anyway - so for example this is one of them:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.applicationWillUnhide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSApplicationWillUnhide, object: nil)
```

but still nothing.

All of this is done at the appDelegate.swift file.
(maybe needless to say, but the function applicationDidFinishLaunching which is also declared at NSApplicationDelegate is getting called)

Anyone has a clue on this?

Comment: Yes it is (I think it's the default): class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate

Comment: They are normally called as appropriate. Do you need a counterexample?

Comment: No, I guessed something is wrong somewhere, I just have no idea what it is.

Comment: If I'm looking at the storyboard, the Application's delegate is correct (App Delegate), but the received actions (hide, unhide..) are all empty circles, not connecting to anything

Answer (score 0):

While cleaning the project was helpful, only applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidBecomeActive were getting called.
So I ended up implementing NSWindowController that comfort to NSWindowDelegate, and there I have windowWillMiniaturize, windowWillClose and windowDidDeminiaturize